# See GitHub issues created during a specific time range

Tags: github, github-search

I would like to view all of the GitHub issues opened during a specific time range for a single repository. For example, all issues opened during the month of December 2022.

I can query for issues created after a specific date with the following query: `is:issue created:>2022-12-01`, however attempting to limit the search to exclude issues opened after December 31st is not currently working for me. And I don't immediately see the syntax in the GitHub documentation [1].

[1] https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `range` operator for these searches (which is `..`):

`is:issue is:open created:2022-01-01..2022-12-31` .

See the docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-dates

Comment: **Two** periods (`..`), not three periods (`...`), that was my problem!